# Spring - Failed to introspect Class from ClassLoader

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to invoke a start() method from main by using the ApplicationContext. However i see the exception below. Any help is appreciated.

Main Application:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("Hello Elastic!!");

    ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(TestElastic.class);
    DeploymentStep app = context.getBean(DeploymentStep.class);

   
    app.start();
}
```

Config class to wire up the bean:

@Configuration
public class TestElastic {

```
@Bean
public DeploymentStep app(){
    return new DeploymentStep();
}
```

}

DeploymentStep class:

public class DeploymentStep
{

```
@Autowired RestHighLevelClient client;

public void start()
{ ... Business Logic }
```

}

Exception:

Hello Elastic!!
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'app' defined in com.example.TestElastic: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [com.example.DeploymentStep] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@33909752]